# How to get the expiration times of cache values properly in Django?

Tags: python, caching, django-cache, cache-expiration, django-caching

I set 3 cache values with `timeout` and get the expiration times with `cache._expire_info` in [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("name", "John", timeout=60)
cache.set("age", 36, timeout=120)
cache.set("gender", "Male", timeout=180)

print(cache._expire_info)
```

But, the expiration times are hidden in numbers as shown below:

```
{':1:name': 1692720916.654848, ':1:age': 1692720976.654848, ':1:gender': 1692721036.654848}
```

Actually, the result which I expected is as shown below:

```
{':1:name': 60, ':1:age': 120, ':1:gender': 180}
```

So, how can I get the expiration times of the cache values properly in Django?